# Expanding Recurrence Relation and Finding Closed Form

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recurrence

I have a snippet of algorithm and must find the worst-case recurrence and find its closed form. So far I have the worst-case recurrence:

```
T(n)= 2T(n/4) + C for n > 1.
```

I tried expanding it, and I have this form currently:

T(n) = 2<sup>k</sup>T(n/4<sup>k</sup>) + Ck

with k = log<sub>4</sub>(n) or k = (log<sub>2</sub>(n))/2.

I have T(1) = 1000.

I am at a loss on what to do next, or how to find its closed form exactly. I still cannot see a pattern in the algorithm or my expansion of T(n). Any insight would be great, thank you.

Comment: This is a simple arithmetic sequence, not exponential sequence. T + c, 3/2T + c, 2T + c, 5/2T + c, 3T + c, 7/2T + c,

Comment: Consider what _k_ represents in your intermediate form. What is its relationship to _n_? Especially think about the the time where _n_ = 1, so you can use _T(1)_.

Comment: @JohnC I substituted n/4^k as 1, and that is also where I got k = 0.5log2(n). When I use T(1) in the equation, it becomes 2000*2^(0.5log2(n)) + C*0.5log2(n). Should I then substitute the n with incrementing values to find a common pattern?

Comment: No, that should _be_ the pattern, a function of _n_, so you're almost there. However, that's not the simplest form of the first term. Logarithms and exponents are inverse operations, after all...

Answer (score 2):

What you can get is a closed formula when n = 4^k:

```
T(4^k) = 2^k x 10^3 + C + 2C + ... + 2^(k-1)C
       = 2^k x 10^3 + (2^k - 1)C
```

Where the last eqaulity comes from the geometric series formula.

For all other n, I think the best you can do is to apply the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Your equation falls in case 1 of the theorem (you have a = 2, b = 4, c = 0).
Therefore:

```
log_b(a) = 1 / 2
```

and

```
T(n) = O(sqrt(n))
```

I'm not sure if it admits an unique closed form.

Comment: thanks! I thought its closed form is in the form of a geometric series (with sigma and stuff) so I was looking for that kind of form... but I guess if we have its T(n) and a closed formula when n=4^k it would work too.. my teacher hinted that the code we get the recurrence from will loop infinitely though... not sure if that adds up to the kind of closed form she is looking for. But thanks a lot!